# LIB OKHTTP How to sent value null into $_POST?

Tags: android

hollow
i want sent valuse null into PHP. than php get $_POST
My code.

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM) 
                            // post request
                    .addFormDataPart("test", null)
                    .build();


            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(localhost/testnull.php)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();
```

OK HTTP can't sent null. it's error.

thk every body

Comment: If you could send it then how would it look in php? Please give an example.

Comment: <?php
$str=$_POST['test'];
if ($id==null){
 $str="is null";
}else{
 $str="not null";
}
echo "text =".$str;
?>

i'm not sure error php or android

Comment: You are mixing up $id and $str. And 'test'.

Comment: sorry actually $id is $str. but  i'm echo $str is not thing
 thak you for anwer.